# Get Method not found

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve the string in foo1 from bar, but the getFoo() methods are for some reason not getting read. Here is the bar class.

```
class bar 
{
   final String foo1;
   final String foo2;
   final String foo3; 
   bar(String foo1, String foo2, String foo3) 
   { 
      this.foo1 = foo1;
      this.foo2 = foo2;
      this.foo3 = foo3;
   }
   String getFoo1(){
       return foo1;
   }
   String getFoo2(){
       return foo2;
   }
   String getFoo3(){
       return foo3;
   }
}
```

Here is the code trying to access Foo1

```
Map<String, bar> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("main1", new bar("foo1", "foo2", "foo3"));
"main1".getFoo1();
```

Comment: Use "main1" to get the bar from the map, and then call getFoo1() on the bar. In your code you are trying to call getFoo1() on the string "main1".

Comment: `"main1".getFoo1();` tries to call `getFoo1()` from the string "main1". To get the real `bar` object, use `map.get("main1").getFoo1()`

Comment: "main1" - is an String object. And String have no getFoo1() method.

Comment: Sorry forgot the `()` when writing the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues: first, include parentheses, e.g. `String getFoo1() {` not `String getFoo1 {`.

Secondly, you can't just do `"main1".getFoo1()`, you have to get the `"main1"` entry out of the map:  `map.get("main1").getFoo1()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the '()' from the method names

Try this:

```
class bar 
{
   final String foo1;
   final String foo2;
   final String foo3; 
   bar(String foo1, String foo2, String foo3) 
   { 
      this.foo1 = foo1;
      this.foo2 = foo2;
      this.foo3 = foo3;
   }
   String getFoo1(){
       return foo1;
   }
   String getFoo2(){
       return foo2;
   }
   String getFoo3(){
       return foo3;
   }
}
```

Also, you cannot just do "main".getFoo1();
Try:

```
map.get("main1").getFoo1();
```

Answer (score 1):

this is incorrect

```
"main1".getFoo1();
```

as `getFoo1()` is not a method of a string.

I think you are looking for

```
map.get("main1").getFoo1();
```

this will get the `foo` object out of the map, whose key is *main1*.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the getFoo1 method on the string object "main1" rather than the bar object. I think what you meant to do is get the value from the map using the key "main1" and then call getFoo1. Like this: map.get("main1").getFoo1();

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve the element from map and then access it. The code above only access the methods on java.lang.String class

```
Map<String, bar> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("main1", new bar("foo1", "foo2", "foo3"));
map.get("main1").getFoo1();
```